# Serf client cannot connect to RPC client running locally

Tags: go, serf

I am initializing my agent like this:

```
    conf := serf.DefaultConfig()
    conf.NodeName = "node-a"
    conf.MemberlistConfig.BindAddr = "127.0.0.1"
    conf.MemberlistConfig.BindPort = 6666
    conf.MemberlistConfig.AdvertiseAddr = "127.0.0.1"
    conf.MemberlistConfig.AdvertisePort = 6666
```

I also have a client code that is trying to connect to the RPC client:

```
    c, err := client.NewRPCClient("127.0.0.1:7373")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error creating RCP Client:", err)
        return
    }
```

I start my agent and I see this output:

```
2020/05/06 07:15:18 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node-a 127.0.0.1
[{node-a 127.0.0.1 6666 map[] alive 1 5 2 2 5 4}]
```

When I start my client, I get this:

```
error creating RCP Client: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7373: connect: connection refused
```

If I start the agent using the CLI as in: `serf agent -bind=0.0.0.0:6667 -advertise=0.0.0.0:6667 -join=0.0.0.0:6666 -node=agent-2 -log-level=debug` and run my client code, it connects to the RPC client.

I am sure there is a mistake in my code or in my understanding of how Serf works.

Comment: Is it correct that bind and advertise ports are the same?

Comment: @bgnfu7re, yes, that is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood what I was doing wrong.

My objective is to have a Serf cluster and make the nodes communicate with each other. To do that, I have to start the serf services as I was doing but there was no need for a client, the nodes communicate with each other after they joined the cluster.

I will use the Serf client the way I was trying, only if I start the Serf agent via the Serf cli.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you run serf in Go via `serf.Create` (what I assume you are passing the above config to) it only starts a connection to the ports mentioned in the config, and does not start the RPC service.

However, when `serf agent` is run it also [spawns a listener](https://github.com/hashicorp/serf/blob/154dcce0096ceba679558920708b4ff2d60a567c/cmd/serf/command/agent/command.go#L444) on port 7373.

Here is the program I assume you are running for an agent:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/hashicorp/serf/serf"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-c
        fmt.Println("\r- Ctrl+C pressed")
        os.Exit(0)
    }()

    conf := serf.DefaultConfig()
    conf.NodeName = "node-a"
    conf.MemberlistConfig.BindAddr = "127.0.0.1"
    conf.MemberlistConfig.BindPort = 6666
    conf.MemberlistConfig.AdvertiseAddr = "127.0.0.1"
    conf.MemberlistConfig.AdvertisePort = 6666
    serf.Create(conf)
    for {
        fmt.Println("- Sleeping")
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Using netcat, you can see that this is the case:

```
#running my go program
$ nc localhost 7373 -v
nc: connectx to localhost port 7373 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connectx to localhost port 7373 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Versus this output if that TCP port were bound:

```
#running serf agent
$ nc localhost 7373 -v
Connection to localhost port 7373 [tcp/*] succeeded!
```